# How to Generate Random number without repetition in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to generate random numbers within the range of 1-100, without repetition in flutter. And when there are no more numbers to generate (i.e :- every number within 1-100 have been generated randomly without repeats) I want to set a boolean named "noNumbersLeft" to true. How do I do that?

Comment: https://protocoderspoint.com/generate-random-number-dart-program/

Comment: Since your range is relatively small and since it sounds like the number of random numbers you want to generate is comparable to the range, I'd generate a `List<int>` containing all numbers in the desired range, use `List.shuffle`, and then iterate over the shuffled items in order.

Comment: What @jamesdlin says: `var ns = [for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) i]..shuffle();`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments the previous way is inefficient. I've updated that to use `Set` instead of `Map`. But it doesn't make it efficient. Instead you can you can generate a `List` containing 1-100 first and shuffle it. Then you take value from this shuffled list until it's empty.

```
final rnList = List<int>.generate(100, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();

while (rnList.isNotEmpty) {
  final rn = rnList.removeLast();
  // do sth with the number
}
```

**INEFFICIENT**

This while loop will create all the numbers from 1-100 without repetition.

```
final generatedRandoms = <int>{};

final rng = Random();
while (generatedRandoms.length < 100) {
  final gr = rng.nextInt(100) + 1;
  generatedRandoms.add(gr);
}
```

Now if you need the random number generation happens at different times, say when user taps on a button, the approach stays the same. You use a set, map or array where you keep track of generated numbers. If the number is generated already you call `rng.nextInt` until you get a number that hasn't been generated. Once your map reaches 100 length means you've used them all and then can set `noNumbersLeft` to true.

Comment: Very inefficient solution if you want to generate all 100 numbers since it get worse to generate a valid random number the more you have generated. Also, instead of `Map<int, bool>` you could just use a `Set<int>`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the use of Set<int>

Comment: Just make it `final generatedRandoms = <int>{};`, then `if (generatedRandoms.contains(gr)) ...` and `generatedRandoms.add(gr);`.
I'd actually use a list instead: `final generatedRandoms = List<bool>.filled(100, false);`, with `if (generatedRandoms[gr]) ...` and `generatedRandoms[gr] = true;`.

In any case, it's inefficient because of the algorithm, not the way it stores boolean flags.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:math';

int generateUniqueRandomNumber(numbers, maxNumber) {
  int randomNumber = Random().nextInt(maxNumber) + 1;

  if (numbers.contains(randomNumber)) {
    randomNumber = generateUniqueRandomNumber(numbers, maxNumber);
  }
  return randomNumber;
}

void main() {
  const noOfUniqueNumbersToGenerate = 5;
  const maxNumber = 100;
  List<int> uniqueNumbers = [];

  while (uniqueNumbers.length < noOfUniqueNumbersToGenerate) {
    final randomNumber = generateUniqueRandomNumber(uniqueNumbers, maxNumber);
    uniqueNumbers.add(randomNumber);
  }
  print("genererated numbers list : $uniqueNumbers");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int max = 101;
  int RandomNumber = Random().nextInt(max);
  print(RandomNumber);
}
```

This should generate and print a random number from 0 to 100.

**OR**

```
 import 'dart:math';
    
    void main()  {
int max = 101;
      var rng = new Random();
      for (var i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        print(rng.nextInt(max ));
      }
    }
```

No Need to set any flag(boolean named "noNumbersLeft")

Comment: This could generate repeated numbers while the author wants no repetition.